# Userscript in javascript/jQuery to watch a page for specific changes in link text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I'm trying to create a userscript to watch a page for changes in link text. The script should:

1. Refresh after 10 seconds the page if there are no links present.
2. Refresh the page if there are links present but contain a keyword that I don't want (in this example the word i don't care about is "phone").
3. Alert me when there is a link present that doesn't contain the keyword (even if there is another think that contains said keyword). In this example, the word that should trigger it should be "email", but I also want to be alerted whenever there is a link that just doesn't contain the word "phone".

[I've come up with a jsfiddle to sort of simulate the page I would be watching with this script here](https://jsfiddle.net/ad9z23f5/4/), the top section is simply to simulate the random changes on the page that may take place. In the example I would want to be alerted when the keyword "email" appears, whether or not the other link is present.

And here is my horrible attempt at trying to write this. I don't know why but I just can't seem to wrap my head around the proper logic and loop needed to accomplish this. I've been all over the place with this and now it's probably such a mess that it's not even a useful jumping off point anymore. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var workLinks = $("td > a").length,
        newLink = false,
    i = -1;

function reloadPage() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
  }, 10000);
}

console.log(workLinks);

if (workLinks === 0) {

  reloadPage();

} else if (workLinks > 0) {

  while (newLink === false && i < links) {

    i++;
    var links = $("td > a").eq(i).text();

    if (links.indexOf('phone') < -1) {
      alert('New link');
      newLink = true;
      break;
    } else {
      reloadPage();
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: well to start, you check if `newWork === false` down in where the `while()` loop starts but you seem to have meant `newLink`

Comment: Good eye. Just walked away and came back and noticed another issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, Deryck pointed out an error and then I found some more. I had a few wrongly named variables. And tried a for loop again. This time it worked.

[Here's the working jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ad9z23f5/5/)

Here's the edited code:

```
var workLinks = $("td > a").length;

function reloadPage() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
  }, 10000);
}

console.log(workLinks);

if (workLinks === 0) {

  reloadPage();

} else if (workLinks > 0) {

  var links = $('td > a').length;

  for (i = 0; i < links; i++) {

        var links = $("td > a").eq(i).text();

    if (links.indexOf('phone') < 0) {
      alert('New link');
      break;
    } else {
      reloadPage();
    }
  }  
}
```